# Probability that a randomly selected card is an ace (Bayes theorem)

Tags: probability, combinatorics

$n$ cards are randomly chosen from $52$ standard cards ($n<52$). One of the $n$ cards was checked, and it turned out to be an ace. This card was returned to the $n$ cards, after which the deck was shuffled. One card is chosen randomly again from these $n$ cards. What is the probability that this card is an ace?

I am approaching the problem this way: if choose the first ace again (with $\frac{1}{n}$ probability), we, of course, see this ace. 
Otherwise, for any of the remaining $n-1$ cards, the probability to see an ace equals $\frac{3}{51}$. So the answer is $\frac{1+\frac{n-1}{17}}{n}$
Is that correct?

I was also trying to solve this problem in a more straightforward manner. The total probability for there to be an ace among $n$ cards equals:

$$ \frac{\binom{4}{1}\binom{48}{n-1}+\binom{4}{2}\binom{48}{n-2}+\binom{4}{3}\binom{48}{n-3}+\binom{4}{4}\binom{48}{n-4}}{\binom{52}{6}}$$

How do I take account of the fact that one ace is definitely among the $n$ cards?

Comment: A priori, there are $5$ cases to consider according to the number of aces amongst the $n$ cards.  We can easily compute the, a priori, probabilities of each case.  Now, having selected an ace from the $n$, these probabilities change.  For example, the probability that the $n$ contain no aces is now $0$.  Use Bayes' to compute the a posteriori probabilities.

Comment: Note:  you say that the ace is returned to "the deck" but this is ambiguous.  Do you mean that it is returned to the special $n$ cards or that it is returned to the remainder of the deck?

Comment: @lulu, it's returned to the special $n$ cards

Comment: That's what I figured, but I think you should clarify that in the post.

Comment: For example, let $P(A_{k}|B)$ be the a posteriori probability to have $k$ aces given that we have seen an ace. It equals:

$$ \frac{\binom{4}{k} \cdot \binom{48}{n-k}\cdot \frac{k}{n}}{\binom{4}{1}\binom{48}{n-1}\frac{1}{n}+\binom{4}{2}\binom{48}{n-2}\frac{2}{n}+\binom{4}{3}\binom{48}{n-3}\frac{3}{n}+\binom{4}{4}\binom{48}{n-4}\frac{4}{n}}$$ Right?

Comment: Do those values sum to $1$?

Comment: @lulu, see my edit above. Now they sum to 1.

Comment: Now I agree with those probabilities.

Comment: Now for each of those 4 probabilities, I need to multiply $P(A_{k}|B)$by $\frac{k}{n}$ and sum. Doesn't sound very promising in terms of arithmetics, but I guess this is all that is left, right? :)

Comment: That's the way to go.  I'd run some sanity checks at the end...say $n=1$, or $n=52$ for instance.  Just because the arithmetic is so messy.

Comment: @lulu, thank you very much for your help. I have checked the formula (it's awful), and the two results coincide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that there are $k$ aces among the rest $(n-1)$ cards is:
$$
\frac{\binom3k\binom{48}{n-k-1}}{\binom{51}{n-1}}.
$$
Thus the probability in question is:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^3\frac{\binom3k\binom{48}{n-k-1}}{\binom{51}{n-1}}\frac{k+1}n.
$$
The result coincides with your much simpler answer.

Comment: Thank you. This is a great approach! Can you please take a look at my last comment under the OP? I have recalculated a posteriori probabilities. Now I can just sum the products of each probability $P(A_{k}|B)$ and $\frac{k}{n}$. Is that correct?